# Надо сграбить сайт в странной кодировке

Tags: кодировка, ruby, кириллица, cp1251, nokogiri

Что мы имеем.

> page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.mirstroek.ru/companies/"), nil,
>   'UTF-8') elements = table.css("td.pad-top1")
>
> elements = Iconv.conv('windows-1252', 'utf-8', elements.to_s)

Что мы имеем в результате.

> ?????????????, ???????,
>   ???????????????????????????,
>   ????????????

При том если я иконву укажу 1251, то словлю

> mir_grabber.rb:58:in `conv': "Ñòðîèòåëüñòâî, î"...
>   (Iconv::IllegalSequence)

Парни я его и так и сяк. А он мне вопросики выдает. Как сделать чтобы русский был нормальный? Что еще. Я могу указать кодировку прямо в нокогири, но при этом получу те же самые вопросики и без всякого иконва.

---

Прошу прощения за неполную информацию. Итак.require 'http'

```
@r = HTTP.get("http://www.mirstroek.ru/companies/")
@r.headers["text/html; charset=cp1251"]

puts @r
```

Принес нам:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/http-2.2.1/lib/http/headers.rb:209:in
`normalize_header': Invalid HTTP header field name: "text/html;
charset=cp1251" (HTTP::InvalidHeaderNameError)  from
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/http-2.2.1/lib/http/headers.rb:59:in `get'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/http-2.2.1/lib/http/headers.rb:69:in
`[]'    from mir_grabber.rb:50:in `<main>'
```

И кстати пользуясь случаем, что столько людей читает этот вопрос и люди эти видимо пишут на руби, ну я вообще на перле пишу больше, но не важно. Я хотел бы послушать ваше мнение относительно редактора. Я много лет пользуюсь Komodo от ActiveState. Но последнюю неделю я стал замечать за ним, что он хотя и показывает, что записывает удаленный код, но не делает этого. Приходится несколько раз жать на запись, чтобы записались изменения точно.
Что посоветуете комрады?

Comment: Зачем вы жестко указываете Nokogiri кодировку UTF-8 в качестве кодировки страницы, не смотря на то, что сами понимаете что кодировка там Windows-1251? И почему вы решили потом конвертировать результат используя iconv, вместо того что бы поправить вызов `Nokogiri::HTML`?

Comment: Да потому что я писал нокогири кодировку WINDOWS-1251 и имел все теже вопросики на выходе. Тут где что писать не особо важно. Важно понять как из этого порочного круга выбраться.

Comment: Сайт 100% в кодировке 1251, открывайте его именно в этой кодировке.

Comment: page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.mirstroek.ru/companies/"), nil, 'WINDOWS-1251')  
Возвращает гору вопросиков. К сожалению.

Comment: И это тоже не ответ. Вы вообще читаете, что я пишу в комментариях? `@r.headers["text/html; charset=cp1251"]` вообще комментировать не буду, где вы это взяли? ._.

Comment: Я простите что-то сделал не так?

Comment: Все все все я исправился. Я просто подумал что туда надо прописать типичный контент тайп. Однако, даже после @r.body.to_s.encode("UTF-8") в коде все равно только вопросики.

Comment: Возможно, это место (окно консоли какое-нибудь?), куда вы выводите, категорически не умеет выводить кириллицу. Или руби выводит не в той кодировке, в которой это место умеет. Попробуйте вывести в файл и посмотреть там.

Comment: Да я срочным макаром переношу скрипт на свой мак потому что пришел к сходным выводам.

Comment: Если окно консоли не умеет UTF-8, в нём будут приколы. Если умеет, то где-то что-то сделано не так. Я опробовал код из своего ответа у себя, у меня консоль точно умеет UTF-8 и кириллицу со страницы превосходно выводит. Если у вас не выводит, опишите среду детальнее, т. к. проблема в ней, не в руби.Ну, или в очень старом руби, но у вас 2.3.0. Вывод в файлы должен быть "как есть", пробуйте на нём.  И это всё ещё не ответ и подлежит удалению.

Comment: И бинго. Мой мак показывает нормальный русский текст.

Comment: Но смысл такой что даже после
puts @r.body.to_s.encode("UTF-8")
puts @r.body.to_s.encoding
Он выводит Windows-1251, так что получается encode не отработал.

Comment: Нет, он отработал, просто вы не знаете, как работает `.encode` и поленились посмотреть :) Он возвращает **новую** строку с тем же содержимым, но в указанной кодировке. То, что вы ожидали увидеть (перекодировать уже имеющуюся), делает не `encode`, а `encode!`.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы. Все работает на ура. Огромное вам спасибо за оказанную помощь. Она просто неоценима, сам бы я разбирался ооочень долго.

Answer (score 4):

Зачем вы указываете кодировку явно, если **сайт вам явно её возвращает**?

```
require 'http'
@r = HTTP.get(url)
@r.headers["Content-Type"] # => "text/html; charset=cp1251"
#                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

И более того, нормальный HTTP-клиент (не `Kernel.open`, а `HTTP`) способен это понять и выбрать для строки соответствующую кодировку:

```
@r.body.to_s.encoding # => #<Encoding:Windows-1251>
```

Просто `Kernel.open` это очень общая штука, которая открывает просто какой-то IO-поток, и не знает приблизительно ничего о том, что в нём. (У меня вообще `open` с HTTP'шными URL не работает, на Ruby 2.3.1.) HTTP-клиенту известно заметно больше, поскольку протокол позволяет передавать не только сами данные, но и метаданные, в заголовках.

Полученную кодировку Nokogiri учтёт при разборе документа. Хотя при желании можно перевести в UTF-8 и вручную, это реализовано в классе `String`, не надо никуда дополнительно лезть:

```
@r.body.to_s.encode("UTF-8")
```

Вы в Ruby, видимо, недавно, так что замечу, что этот кусочек вернёт **новую строку** в указанной кодировке, а старая останется неизменной. В Ruby достаточно часто делают изменяющие методы парами: не деструктивный и деструктивный. Деструктивный меняет существующий объект и имеет имя вида `метод!` (вызов как `объект.метод!(аргументы)`). Существует метод `encode!`, подчиняющийся этому правилу.

Comment: Дааа... но я же тогда не смогу разбирать полученный код нокогири, так как это не ее объект. А это печально. Учитывая мои объемы. Это катастрофа.

Comment: @DenisAntonov а вы пробовали? Я попробовал, прекрасно работает. Nokogiri отлично принимает обычные строки. Откуда взялось утверждение про "не её объект", даже предполагать боюсь.

Comment: Хотяяя... html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<html><body><h1>Mr. Belvedere Fan Club</h1></body></html>")
Я смогу подсунуть этот полученный код нокогири для разбора. Да я сейчас так и попробую. Главное избавится от вопросиков.

Comment: @DenisAntonov во-о-от. Привыкайте сначала пытаться, а потом унывать :)